# Best way to implement temporary overlays in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, popup, overlay

I'm writing an app that connects to network resources.

When the app is connecting, I want to popup an overlay with the usual spinney progress graphic and a cancel button. I have designed a `ConnectProgressViewModel` and matching `ConnectProgressView` for the overlay.

My question is what is the cleanest way to show/hide the overlay from the parent ViewModel?

**A)** Expose a constant `ConnectProgressViewModel` from my parent ViewModel, and have the `ConnectProgressView` bind its visibility to the `ConnectProgressViewModel.IsConnecting` property.

**B)** Expose a generic `Overlay` property from the parent ViewModel, and set it to a `ConnectProgressViewModel`  when the user wants to connect. The parent View binds a `ContentControl` to this `Overlay` property and data templating takes care of the rest.

**C)** ?

The first seems to encapsulate the functionality more, with the app not having to care about showing and hiding the overlay, but exposing a constant `ConnectProgressViewModel` all the time feels wrong when it's only show occasionally.

The second seems to fit MVVM better with the `ConnectProgressViewModel` only being created when it's needed, but it places more functionality onto the parent, and also the generic Overlay property feels a bit weird too.

Cheers

**EDIT:**

I should clarify that this view does more than just show busy status. It allows cancelling/retries and selection of different network resources etc. I omitted such details for brevity which was perhaps a mistake as people are concentrating on the busy indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always just use a `BusyIndicator` from the Silverlight Toolkit.  It does not have a cancel button, but you can probably style it to have one.  The `BusyIndicator` has an `IsBusy` property that I bind to an `IsBusy` property on my ViewModel.  If you style the control to have a button, you can add a cancel command to your ViewModel.

**Edit**

I just saw that this is WPF not Silverlight.  I'm not sure if the WPF Toolkit has a BusyIndicator

**Edit Again**

It looks like the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) has a BusyIndicator.  Note, I have no experience with this.

Comment: The BusyIndicator is automatically shown when IsBusy is true and hidden when IsBusy is false.

Comment: Yeah just had a look at the WPF Toolkit version, thanks. It appears to be there all the time, and shows/hides itself like my A).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like your suggestion in A) and argue that you shouldn't implement something as generic like B) until you actually have that degree of flexibility as a requirement, like being able to show different overlay views.

Keep it simple!